# Team Foundation alternatives for .net applications with a GIT repository

Tags: c#, .net, git, tfs, continuous-integration

I´m trying to setup a Continuous Integration environment with Git restriction (I mean GIT must be the code repository) and I can´t use team foundation. The question is... does GIT support the Build Automatization? And the code analysis? and the test execution?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my ignorance.

Cheers,
Kike.

Answer (score 1):

Git is just a source control repository, it doesn't "support" build Automation, but any decent build automation tool will support Git.

You mentioned Jenkins, this is a good Automation tool which will allow you to create workflows or orchestrations to provide CI functionality. Another good alternative it Team City, although Jenkins is FOSS and TeamCity is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

I´m answering myself ;) it seems Jenkins also support .net code so problem resolved at least for me (which is the only thing that matters for me muahahaha!!!)
http://justinramel.com/2013/01/15/5-minute-setup/

Sonar also supports it
http://www.happiestminds.com/blogs/how-to-set-up-sonar-on-jenkins-for-net-projects/

Bamboo supposes an amazing solution as well
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-net-and-bamboo-289277288.html